# Failed: InvalidBatch : Failed to process query: FUNCTIONALITY_NOT_ENABLED: Foreign Key Relationships not supported in Bulk Query

Tags: soql, bulk, translation-workbench

I am getting below error on running bulk query.Is there any way i can get result in bulk query.

> Failed: InvalidBatch : Failed to process query:
>   FUNCTIONALITY_NOT_ENABLED: Foreign Key Relationships not supported in
>   Bulk Query

I have used below bulk query in workbench.

```
SELECT Product__c,product__r.description FROM Sales_Quota__c
```

Comment: I don't think this question has anything to do with translations? Simple search to find the answer here, for example https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000h8WkAAI

Comment: @adrian-I wanted for bulk query. That foreign and parent relationship is already enabled in workbench.It is just not working with bulk query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best bet is just to define a field on the `Sales_Quota__c` Object called `Product_Description__c`, which would be a formula equal to `product__r.description`. Then use this in your query.

```
SELECT Product__c,Product_Description__c FROM Sales_Quota__c
```

Answer (score 1):

v39.0 API is currently supporting `Relationship fields`.

> https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.204.0.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_using_bulk_query.htm

v39.0 API - Bulk API query doesn’t support the following SOQL:

- COUNT
- ROLLUP
- SUM
- GROUP BY CUBE
- OFFSET
- Nested SOQL queries

---

For v38.0 API:-
Bulk API query doesn’t support the following SOQL:
COUNT

- ROLLUP
- SUM
- GROUP BY CUBE
- OFFSET
- Nested SOQL queries
- ***Relationship fields***